# Dynamic style in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, jsx

In react, in my home page, I have four columns. And I need to change their size independently. When I clic on one of the four columns, I can change his size, but I don't know how to change in the same time the size of the other columns. Aim is to render the clicked column's with a big size and the three other columns with a small size. But I have no idea.

My code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Column from '../components/Column';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

resizeColumn() {
  alert('ok');
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="container home-menu flex row between">
      <Column parentOnClick={ this.resizeColumn } text={ 'React' } key={ 'Column 1' }/>
      <Column parentOnClick={ this.resizeColumn } text={ 'For' } key={ 'Column 2' }/>
      <Column parentOnClick={ this.resizeColumn } text={ 'The' } key={ 'Column 3' }/>
      <Column parentOnClick={ this.resizeColumn } text={ 'Win' } key={ 'Column 4' }/>
    </div>
  );
 } 
}

export default Home;


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Column extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columnDimension: ''
    }
  }

  resizeColumn() {
    this.style = {flex: 20};
    this.setState({columnDimension: 20});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={ (e) => this.resizeColumn(e)} style={{flex: this.state.columnDimension}}>

      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default Column;
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, keeping the state in each `Column` will leave you with just that. Each `Column` can handle its own style.

You should *move up* the state one component to `Home`, and keep in `Home`'s state which of the columns is the one that should be wider.

You can have a function like this in `Home`:

```
resizeColumn(columnId) {
  this.setState({ wideColumn: columnId })
}
```

Then, you pass that function as a prop to column

```
<Column onClick={this.resizeColumn} text="React" />
```

And then, in the column component you call that function with its id:

```
<div onClick={() => {this.props.onClick(this.props.text)}} />
```

That way, going back to our `Home` render method, you would have to check the state.

```
<Column onClick={this.resizeColumn} text="React" wide={this.state.columnId === 'React'} />
```

And then you could use the `wide` prop to set the wide style or not to each `Column`

Answer (score 0):

First, the `Home` component should be the one keeping track of which column is the active ("big") one. Put that in the state of `Home`.

Then you already have the `resizeColumn()` method of `Home`, which you correctly pass to the column components as a prop, so the columns can call it when clicked. They need to send something identifying themselves with the function call, so `Home` knows which one was clicked. The method updates the state of `Home` so it knows which column should be active.

Finally, `Home` must tell the columns which one is the big one, so they can render themselves correctly. I observe that the class names are pretty bootstrap-like. You could give the big column a class name of `col-lg-6`, while the others get `col-lg-2` or something

Exactly how this is done is left as an exercise for the reader. Hope this helps

PS: Methods in React have a tendency to lose context when used as event listeners, meaning use of `this` inside them will not work. You need to bind them before use. An example of how the `constructor` of the `Home` class could be:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // Set initial state
  this.state = {
    bigCol: 1
  };

  // Bind methods
  this.resizeColumn = this.resizeColumn.bind(this);
}
```

and then an example of how a `Column` component would be created:

```
<Column
  key="1"
  className={this.state.bigCol === 1 ? "col-lg-6" : "col-lg-2"}
  onClick={this.resizeColumn.bind(this, 1)}
  text="React"
  />
```